# Java .Jar Image Not Showing Up

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, jar

I made an application in Java (using the Eclipse IDE) and i refer in the code to images stored in a source folder called "source" and it worked fine in the IDE. When I extracted the jar to an runnable jar, there are no errors but the picture doesn't show up, or if it does it just shows whatever's behind it. I opened up the .jar in WinRar and it appears the pictures are all thrown in with the class files. How can I fix this?

```
Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("sources/SystemTrayOne.png");
```

Comment: can you show us the relevant code? You're not referring to the images as files in the Jar are you? Or are they being accessed as resources? Do you see any exceptions? Do you have any empty catch blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to get a file which doesn't exist in a Jar. Instead get the URL via the `Class#getResource(...)`

e.g.,

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource(....); // resource name here
Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imgUrl);
```

or better

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource(....); // resource name here
Image i = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
```

Comment: where should i put the image?

Comment: Leave the image where it's located as that's not the issue. The issue is how you retrieve it. The String required for `getResources(...)` will be the image file name with the path relative to your class file location.

Comment: it worked but Eclipse neglected to put everything in my "source" folder into a seperate folder i had to do that myself

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue till yesterday. I have got a fix for this. Let me share it with you.

- In your Eclipse, go to your Project name.
- Right your project name.
- New -> Source file/folder
- Name this Source file/folder as images
- Now on your local machine go to the Eclipse workspace where your project
  is physically present.
- Copy ALL your images into the newly created 'images' folder right there only.
- Now go back to Eclipse.
- Right click on your Project -> Refresh
- Now, wherever you are using images in your .java files , go to those lines and prefix the image location with images/

Example : XXX xxx = XXXX (example.jpg) Change it with .... XXX xxx = XXXX (images/example.jpg)

BOOM !! The images will be shown when you run the .jar file.

NOTE : Do not run the .jar file from cmd using java -jar AppName.jar Instead, just double click the .jar file and you will be seeing the images.

If it works for you, kindly upvote. :)